# How do I use this color object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, nested

I do have an array of objects (book) here. My question is: How do I use the "color" object so each book has its color property? I think it has to be something like this -> book[amount].color <- but I can't make it work.

I don't know how to call the color property.

This is the array of objects:

```
var book = [

    {title: "The Giver",
    stars: 3,
    author: "Lowry Loys",
    color: color(0, 38, 255), //How do I make this property work in the code?
    image: true},

    {title: "How to win friends",
    stars: 5,
    author: "Dale Carnegie",
    color: color(214, 255, 219),
    image: false},

    {title: "Principios fund. de la filosofía",
    stars: 5,
    author: "Georges Politzer",
    color: color(115, 0, 255),
    image: false}
];
```

This is the code

```
 // draw shelf
    fill(173, 117, 33);
    rect(0, 120, width, 10);

// draw books + title + author
for (var amount = 0; amount < book.length; amount++) { //draw books
    fill(214, 255, 219);
    rect(154*amount, 20, 90, 100);
    fill(0, 0, 0);
    textSize(13);
    text(book[amount].title, 5 + 158*amount, 27, 68, 100); //draw title
    textSize(10);
    text(book[amount].author, 5 + 155*amount, 91, 75, 100); //draw author

    for (var s = 0; s < book[amount].stars; s++) { //draw stars
    image(getImage("cute/Star"), 11 + s * 15 + amount * 151, 98, 15, 22);
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < book[amount].image; i++) { //draw stars
    image(getImage("avatars/aqualine-sapling"), 9 + i * 60 + amount * 46, 42, 36, 39);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unless `color` is a function `color: color(0, 38, 255),` isn't going to work as an object property. It probably needs to be `color: 'color(0, 38, 255)',`.

Comment: `book[amount].color` is the correct way to access it. What error are you getting?

Comment: do you have a `color` function somewhere else in your code?

Comment: No, I dont have a function.

Comment: Then please check my answer

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a `color` function, you'll have to quote those properties and then extract the color information.

In this simple example a regex grabs the color values from the (index 1) object, and then sets the background color of a temporary element.

```js
var book=[{title:"The Giver",stars:3,author:"Lowry Loys",color:'color(0, 38, 255)',image:!0},{title:"How to win friends",stars:5,author:"Dale Carnegie",color:'color(214, 255, 219)',image:!1},{title:"Principios fund. de la filosofía",stars:5,author:"Georges Politzer",color:'color(115, 0, 255)',image:!1}]

const result = document.getElementById('result');
const color = book[1].color.match(/(\d+)/g);
result.style.backgroundColor = getColor(color);

function getColor(color) {
  return `rgb(${color[0]}, ${color[1]}, ${color[2]})`;
}
```

```html
<div id="result">sdfdsfdsf</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The color function doesn't exist in plain javascript. I think the easiest way will be to store your colors as a HEXs in strings like below:

```
var book = [{
    title: "The Giver",
    stars: 3,
    author: "Lowry Loys",
    color: "#0026ff", // converted rgb(0, 38, 255)
    image: true
}];

book[0].color; // "#0026ff"
```

You can use e.g. [this](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm) tool to manually convert colors to HEX. If you don't like it just implement your own `color` function to convert rgb to hex ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)).

[Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/color) you can also find an interesting npm package named Qix-/color:

> JavaScript library for immutable color conversion and manipulation with support for CSS color strings.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much! However, where I am supposed to write this line of code? book[0].color; It doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Inside your `for` loop since it looks like you have access to your book object there? `book[amount].color`